# Edit the application menu on OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing, menu

When you set a JMenu in Swing on OSX, with the title of "Menu", Apple already transforms the menu so it can perform "help" operations?

[image: Menubar Help]

The search bar is automatically added at the top, despite having not manually added such thing. In this context, I can add menus to this "pre-made" menu.

However, how would I do that for the App menu?

[image: App Menu]

Here's an example of what I would like to do:

[image: Safari Menu]

You can see items such as "Safari Extensions...". I need to add my own menu's there, so that my end audience will be able to configure things such as settings.

Is there a way to add JMenuItems to the default application menu in Swing? I'm looking to add extra menu's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually what you find in the app menu are settings-related menu options.  You **can** add a Preferences menu, but that's all -- no further customization beyond that.  To do that you add a `PreferencesHandler`:

```
myApp.setPreferencesHandler(new PreferencesHandler() {
    public void handlePreferences(PreferencesEvent paramPreferencesEvent) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

A Mac user will look there for your app's Preferences.  I'd suggest putting everything settings-related in there.

There isn't really much documentation out there for this anymore, but this tutorial seems to still have a lot of information: http://moomoohk.github.io/snippets/java_osx.html

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I never found this, and this will definitely be useful. Thanks for the link as well. I'm assuming that the handlers are interfaces?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yes, they're interfaces.